# Kafka producer + schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am currently trying to understand on how the schema registry works along with Kafka producers and clients. So I have a kafka producer in python which serilaizes the data to avro by connecting to the schema registry to retrieve the relevant schema. And also I understand from the docs that the schema is retrieved only once when it starts and then uses the schema in its cache. So now, if I change the schema in the registry, how will the producer take the latest version? Should I restart the producer or force it retrieve the latest schema? Or will it automatically retrieve the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

The producer requires the schema locally. It doesn't download it first. That wouldn't make sense for a brand new schema unless you're registering manually, separately

Comment: "It doesn't download it first". But, if it doesn't download it, how does the producer make sure that the produced message is valid according to the confluent schema registry (supposing it uses `KafkaAvroSerializer`)? E.g. the schema that the producer uses (locally) may for some reason not be present on the confluent schema registry at the time of publish.

Comment: @MarinosAn The producer always makes a new schema-register request. If the schema body matches what's in the registry, it just doesn't make a new version. In other words, it's always a POST HTTP request, not a GET for any download. The registry server handles any compatibility of the schema itself, and when the request returns, the client side schema library (i.e. Avro) can still fail if the Kafka record payload provided doesn't adhere to the schema. The serializer code is open source, if you want to learn more

Comment: In the serializer code, I see that `POST HTTP` is only performed when `auto.register.schemas=true`. If it is false there are a couple of other branching statements that all seem to perform a `GET` with specific query params. [Ref](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/ac4fd88a48f92f2dcd8d28b7af139893a62510e7/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java#L115) (e.g. calls `AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.lookupSchemaBySubjectAndId()-> CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId()->getSchemaByIdFromRegistry()->RestService.getId()`)

Comment: @MarinosAn Okay. The code has changed somewhat since I last looked, but the `auto.register.schemas=true` used to always be default behaviour. Still, if a schema isn't available locally, then no request could be serialized. E.g. Avro SpecificRecord types have `SCHEMA$` static field in the classes, and I think Protobuf `Message` type is similar. So - to answer your question, Avro classes are often generated ahead of time, and the client will ensure they are valid; the Registry doesn't need to do that. If you use `GenericRecord`, and `auto.register.schemas=false`, then will be downloaded, sure

Comment: Also note - the question was asking about Python, and `auto.register.schemas` is a Java client property.